# Constructing a point arbitrary close to the Mandelbrot set

Tags: recreational-mathematics, fractals

This question is motivated by the coloring schemes of the Mandelbrot fractal, namely that the [color is determined](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mandelbrot_set#Escape_time_algorithm) by the points *outside* the set, and is proportional to the number of iterations $n_c$ it takes for the mapping, $z_{n+1} = z_{n}^2 + c$ to escape the closed disk $|z_{n_c}|>2$ for a fixed $c\in\mathbb{C}, z_0=0$.

It's observed (and perhaps easy to show?), that the closer one gets to the boundary of the set the larger $n_c$ is. Is there an explicit construction for a complex number $c$ that has an arbitrarily large $n_c$? If one exists, is there one that doesn't involve a perturbation off the real axis?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> If one exists, is there one that doesn't involve a perturbation off the real axis?

Why perturb at all? It's easier to analyse if you stay *on* the real axis.

By consideration of the roots of $z^2 - z + c$, the easy construction is $c = \tfrac14 + \varepsilon$. Without the $\varepsilon$ it would converge to $z \to \tfrac12$; $$(\tfrac12 - \delta + \alpha\varepsilon + O(\varepsilon^2))^2 + \tfrac14 + \varepsilon =
\tfrac12 - (\delta - \delta^2) + (\alpha + 1 - 2\delta\alpha)\varepsilon + O(\varepsilon^2)$$
so $n_c \approx \tfrac{3}{2\varepsilon}$

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Why did you consider the roots to the polynomial $z^2 -z+c$ instead of $z^2+c$?

Comment: @Hooked, one way of seeing it is that $z = z^2 + c$ rearranges to $z^2 - z + c = 0$. Another way is to start by looking at the iteration as bouncing between the lines $y = z^2 + c$ and $y = z$. We want a tiny gap between the lines so that it takes a lot of small steps to get past it.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, the answer makes a lot more sense now!